# Running a loop to plot sub-datasets in R

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

Here's what I want to do.  I have a dataset that resembles Loblolly in R, which is a factor of 14 seeds.  I want to run a loop and scatterplot data from each of the seeds (identity given by 30X where X is an integer) showing height on the y axis and age on the x axis.  The title of each plot would be the seed identity, "30X"

Good lord, I'm not so sure how to do this.  All I know so far is how to plot one scatterplot as follows:

```
xrange<-range(Loblolly$age)
yrange<-range(Loblolly$height)
plot(xrange, yrange, type="n", xlab="Age", ylab="Height")
```

How would you go about doing this iteratively for the whole data set.  Yes, fourteen is still an okay number but say if I wanted to use similar type code for 100 types of seed in another data set, I think you would have to use a for loop, right?  Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a stub to get you there. I build up the different targets in the list and then iterate through them:

```
# multiple plots via a for, with the x = sprintf in the aes call providing contextualized strings as params

varList = list("Var1","Var2","Var3")
plot_list = list()
for (i in 1:3) {
    gg = ggplot(data_set,aes(xfill=factor(RETAINED)))
    gg = gg + aes_string(x = sprintf("log(%s)", varList[[i]])) 
    gg = gg + geom_density(alpha=.3) + labs(x = varList[[i]],y="Density") 
    gg = gg + ggtitle(paste("Distribution of ",varList[[i]],sep=" ")) 
    plot_list[[i]] = gg
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely create a for loop for that, but you can also use a method that splits your dataset based on the `Seed` (groups by that column) and generates a plot for every sub-dataset.

First set you working directory to a folder where you want your plots stored.
Then run this:

```
library(dplyr)

Loblolly %>%
  group_by(Seed) %>%
  do({pdf(paste0(.$Seed,".pdf"))
      plot(.$age, .$height, xlab="Age", ylab="Height", main=unique(.$Seed))
      dev.off()})
```

You should ignore the following error:
`Error: Results are not data frames at positions: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14` and check if the pdfs are created.

In case you don't want to use any libraries you can use:

```
list_seeds = unique(Loblolly$Seed)   # get a list of seeds

for (i in list_seeds) {              # for every seed value

  dt = Loblolly[Loblolly$Seed == i,]    # get a sub-dataset that corresponds to that seed value

  pdf(paste0(i,".pdf"))
  plot(dt$age, dt$height, xlab="Age", ylab="Height", main=i)
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: How would you do it without the library?  I mean I know these shortcuts are nice but it would be helpful to understand the logic in terms of actual loops.